# How to get a weights of Query, Key and Value projection matrices for each distinct head of BERT in HuggingFace implementation?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'm trying to get weights of Query, Key and Value projection matrices of each BERT's attention head. I thought that I can make this via using `model.state_dict()`, but it doesn't give me distinct parameters for each attention head. For example, for a small version of BertForSequenceClassifictation model with two layers and two heads on each, this dict has only the following keys:

```
bert.embeddings.position_ids
bert.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight
bert.embeddings.position_embeddings.weight
bert.embeddings.token_type_embeddings.weight
bert.embeddings.LayerNorm.weight
bert.embeddings.LayerNorm.bias
bert.encoder.layer.0.attention.self.query.weight
bert.encoder.layer.0.attention.self.query.bias
bert.encoder.layer.0.attention.self.key.weight
bert.encoder.layer.0.attention.self.key.bias
bert.encoder.layer.0.attention.self.value.weight
bert.encoder.layer.0.attention.self.value.bias
bert.encoder.layer.0.attention.output.dense.weight
bert.encoder.layer.0.attention.output.dense.bias
bert.encoder.layer.0.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight
bert.encoder.layer.0.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias
bert.encoder.layer.0.intermediate.dense.weight
bert.encoder.layer.0.intermediate.dense.bias
bert.encoder.layer.0.output.dense.weight
bert.encoder.layer.0.output.dense.bias
bert.encoder.layer.0.output.LayerNorm.weight
bert.encoder.layer.0.output.LayerNorm.bias
bert.encoder.layer.1.attention.self.query.weight
bert.encoder.layer.1.attention.self.query.bias
bert.encoder.layer.1.attention.self.key.weight
bert.encoder.layer.1.attention.self.key.bias
bert.encoder.layer.1.attention.self.value.weight
bert.encoder.layer.1.attention.self.value.bias
bert.encoder.layer.1.attention.output.dense.weight
bert.encoder.layer.1.attention.output.dense.bias
bert.encoder.layer.1.attention.output.LayerNorm.weight
bert.encoder.layer.1.attention.output.LayerNorm.bias
bert.encoder.layer.1.intermediate.dense.weight
bert.encoder.layer.1.intermediate.dense.bias
bert.encoder.layer.1.output.dense.weight
bert.encoder.layer.1.output.dense.bias
bert.encoder.layer.1.output.LayerNorm.weight
bert.encoder.layer.1.output.LayerNorm.bias
bert.pooler.dense.weight
bert.pooler.dense.bias
classifier.weight
classifier.bias
```

I.e. it provides, for example, only one query weight matrix for zero layer ( `bert.encoder.layer.0.attention.self.query.weight` ). But zero layer has two heads, so to which of them does this matrix belong? And how to access the weights of the query projection matrix of the **first** and the **second** attention head of zero layer **distinctively**?

P.S. I also tried to look at `model.parameters()`, but it seemingly gives the same matrices, just without names.

P.P.S. I know how to access attention matrix for each head after applying the model to the data sample, but it is not what I need.

Comment: *attention heads* are [different](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/999) from the original transformers implementation. *key*, *value*, *query* dense layers are [scaled](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L260) to the needed size.